I usually miss low battery warning from Windows 10 (while typing...)
I find the coloured banner that appears at ~10% very useful, but only under low keyboard activity... I would love to have something as a corner popup with a long enough timer, which doesn't take keyboard focus, preferably with no need for third-party widgets/apps.

If it happens while I'm typing, I could miss it because I press "Close" without noticing. Is it possible to configure Windows to do something like that?

It's easy to set the display to dim noticeably on low battery -- both a visual warning, and a way to reduce power drain. Just edit the Power Options.

That's a workaround I didn't consider, good. However, I usually want the saving mode pretty early. I'll try if nothing better arises.
